# How to execute file after successful installation?

Tags: installation, wix

How can I execute external file after a successful installation? It's located in the `Windows\System32` folder. `Installer` should not wait for execution finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To launch an application when the user clicks the **Finish** button on "Installation Successful" dialog, the following code will work (Where `LaunchOnExit.exe` refers to ID of installed file that you want to launch)

```
<Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="SetLaunchApplicationTarget" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#LaunchOnExit.exe]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="no" />

    <UI Id="LaunchApplication">
        <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="SetLaunchApplicationTarget">
            <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
        </Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">
            <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
        </Publish>
    </UI>
</Fragment>
```

If you're wanting to launch an application even during a silent installation or MSI rollout, refer @Naishy's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a custom action that describes the application you wish to execute as follows:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" FileKey="YourAppExe" ExeCommand="param1" Execute="immediate" Return="asyncNoWait" />
```

You can then tie this into your installation execute sequence using the following:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Well Done](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson8.php#8.6) section of the WiX Tutorial, it explains how to add Checkbox to launch application after successful installation.